# Too many features in QGIS DXF import: 1 Feature per Column

Tags: qgis, dxf

The company I work for do a considerable amount of field surveys, and export the data directly from the GPS (Leica GS08) to DXF files. 
Whenever I try to open a DXF file (with lines and points), the points in QGIS are displayed in a strange fashion.

[image: DXF file in QGIS]

I opened the same files in ArcGIS, and the result was distinct:

[image: DXF file in ArcGIS]

As you can see, the total amount of features is quite different. In ArcGIS, the system loads 48 features (the same number of points present on the GPS survey), while QGIS loads 288 individual features.

In fact, as it is visible on the Attribute Table, QGIS loads 6 features per GPS point: one feature per "Coordinate", "Height", "Attribute", "Point_Code", "Attribute" and "0" (which are records of the "Layer" column), while ArcGIS loads all these attributes, in one feature.

I have imported the file by dragging the DXF into the QGIS system. I also tried "Another DXF Import/DXF2Shape" plugin, but the result was not the desired one. Although the image presented only one point, there were not a database associated, and the label of the text was not practical.

My issue is that I need QGIS to open these dxf files on the same way ArcGIS does - where each feature may have distinct columns on the attribute table, but not a feature per attribute. As one can imagine, if there is a big concentration of data, is almost impossible to work with the file.

Please find attached a DXF example of the situation in hand. [DXF File Example](http://www.filedropper.com/example_6)

Comment: Please upload a DXF for testing.

Comment: How did you import the DXF file? GRASS plugin v.in.dxf?

Answer (score 1):

What you see are not points, but the position of the texts (label).

You can use the plugin "[Another DXF Importer / DXF2Shape Converter](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/AnotherDXF2Shape/)". 
There, the view is grouped accordingly.

[image]

Comment: This is it! As soon as I saw this, I understood that my brain was not working. Even if the points are not centred with the location taken by the GPS (corresponding to the class '0' on the image), one can select all the points of the class 'Height' and just move them to the desired location..! 
Thank you for your time and help!